# Overriding type attributes of CSS and JS files in HEAD

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I recently installed Magento 2.3 and extended the default Magento Luma theme by creating a custom theme.

I'm trying to override type attributes of default JavaScript and CSS files in the `<HEAD>`.

In other words, I want this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/polyfill.js"></script>
```

to become this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css/custom" media="all" href="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript/custom" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript/custom" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/polyfill.js"></script>
```

Notice the change from `text/javascript` to `text/javascript/custom`. Similar for CSS.

I tried updating my `default_head_blocks.xml` file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css" type="text/css/custom"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js" type="text/javascript/custom"/>
        <script src="mage/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript/custom"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

But what I get is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" type="text/css/custom" media="all" href="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript/custom" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript/custom" src="https://my-mage-url/pub/static/version1574118953/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/polyfill.js"></script>
```

Notice the double type declarations instead of single.

Is there a way to achieve what I described i.e. overriding type attributes for JavaScript and CSS files?

P.S. I know why I need to do this, I'm just not able to explain fully here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find another option to do this besides using `root.phtml`. Here are the steps:

1. Create a `templates` folder under `Magento_Theme` folder in your theme space
2. Create `root.phtml` file inside this directory [`templates`]
3. Open `<Magento_root>/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`, then copy and paste its contents into the root.phtml in your theme space
4. Create a function to modify `$headContent`. I used `preg_replace` with a regular expression to find the duplicate references and then remove what I did not need. It was just a few lines of code.
5. Upload, then flush cache